# Does WSUS include 3rd party patches/drivers?

Tags: windows, wsus, drivers, windows-update, update

I have a WSUS server setup on our network here. It is set to download ALL Windows and Office Updates and store them locally.

Does this include 3rd party drivers and patches as well? Or how does WSUS handle 3rd party patches, firmware and drivers when set to grab from a local WSUS server?

This is 6.3 on Windows Server Datacenter R2.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify your version of WSUS (major version, at least), as the behavior is not the same across all versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, certain drivers are synced with WSUS. Mine has 29'958 drivers which it could sync. However, experience shows that not all drivers are synced to WSUS, so you might still be able to get more drivers if you scan agains WU vs WSUS.